# UrhoSharp losing input when clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, urhosharp

I'm using an UrhoSurface control in WPF. It's included in the NuGet package "UrhoSharp.Wpf". Everything works fine, but when UrhoSurface is clicked with either of the mouse buttons, it stops getting input from the keyboard. Setting Focusable to false doesn't help.
Here's the code I use to get the input:

```
using Urho;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(Key.W))
    CameraNode.Translate(Vector3.UnitZ * moveSpeed * timeStep);
if (Input.GetKeyDown(Key.S))
    CameraNode.Translate(-Vector3.UnitZ * moveSpeed * timeStep);
if (Input.GetKeyDown(Key.A))
    CameraNode.Translate(-Vector3.UnitX * moveSpeed * timeStep);
if (Input.GetKeyDown(Key.D))
    CameraNode.Translate(Vector3.UnitX * moveSpeed * timeStep);
```

I'm fairly new to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a long time since you asked, but in case you or some other still need it: You can use c# way to check if a key is down and it works:

```
if (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.Key.W)) { ... }
```